# Unable to lower innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: linux, mysql

Really frustrating issue. My innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 32M, and I want to lower it. The variable in my.cnf is actually set to 2M, and I can't find any other overriding configuration files (and yes, it's set in the mysqld block). When I try to set the variable at the command line, I get: ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable. Where is the 32M coming from??

**UPDATE**: Is it possible the variable was compiled in and cannot be changed at my.cnf? Or is it possible my Linux distro (openSUSE 11.3) has an include I can't find? And please read below before telling me to change the variable and restart MySQL. That does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can only set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in `my.cnf`. It cannot be set while the database is running.

In any event, 2M is far too small for all but the tiniest test database. 32M is almost certainly too small for any real database. If you're tuning a database server, this is usually the number to *increase*, not *decrease*.

Comment: I'm in the process of moving from one server to another. As I stated above, my databases are running on mysiam, not innodb. Also, as I stated above, it was set as a default of 2M in my my.cnf. I've restarted MYSQL multiple times with no change. Plesk is the only database using innodb tables. On my current server, it's set at 2M and I have no problems. 32M is unnecessary.

Comment: P.S. I should clarify that I know this because 1) I checked SHOW TABLE STATUS on my (Joomla) databases and 2) when I added skip-innodb, the only thing that broke was Plesk. I ran mysqltuner.pl and it confirmed that I had some innodb tables.

Comment: In that case, change it to enough for Plesk and restart MySQL.

Comment: That's kind of the problem: Changing the value and restarting MySQL does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

> My innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 32M

Do you mean you see this value by checking:

```
mysql> select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
+---------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size |
+---------------------------+
|                  33554432 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> and I want to lower it.

Why? How many RAM do you have?

> When I try to set the variable at the command line, I get: `ERROR 1238
>   (HY000): Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' is a read only variable`.

As it said, [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is not a dynamic variable. You cannot change it without restarting MySQL.

> Where is the 32M coming from?

One possible reason is... it is set to 32M in `/etc/my.cnf` originally, and someone change it to 2M but didn't restart MySQL.

Comment: First question: Yes. Answer to second question: The vast majority of my tables are using mysiam, so it doesn't need to be that high. Finally, restarting MySQL does nothing. I should've made that clear in the original question. And it was never set to 32M in my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer to this old question to remark that, as of MySQL 5.7.5, [the InnoDB buffer pool can  be dynamically resized](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize.html) from mysql shell:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=512000000;
```

Comment: It looks that you can not reduce its size dynamically to be lower than actually used at the moment. Otherwise you get "Variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' can't be set to the value of 'YOUR SIZE HERE' error.
In this case you must restart mysql db.